# Fix element at zoom on Phaser3

Tags: phaser-framework

How to fix an element at one point, despite the zoom? `setScrollFactor(x [, y])` doesn't hepl me. 
I have a moving element behind which the camera is moving. But I need to keep the button always in the right corner

Thanks for the fast reply)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a separate scene specifically for the element that you want to remain static

in Phaser 3 multiple scenes can exist at the same time, and they have their own cameras (at least one main camera per scene), which allows you to have scene A with a moving camera rendering the game world, and scene B with a static camera rendering the UI